# Taxes on selling ownership of my software/web service to someone else?

Tags: united-states, taxes, small-business, self-employment

I am not incorporated, just a sole proprietor. I am based in the US. I developed a software package and published it on the web. Recently, I received an offer to sell the web service and transfer all my repositories (code, know-how, etc.) for $100k. If I accept the offer, how will I proceed with this transaction and what type of taxes should I anticipate? I don't have an intellectual property, I am just the developer of the web service.

Comment: Realistically, if $100k were at stake, you would definitely contact an attorney to make sure everything is done properly.

Comment: I hope you didn't accept their first offer.  You should always negotiate because their first offer will be much lower than what they are ultimately willing to pay you.

Comment: This is an interesting point, never thought of! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you didn't indicate whether you are in the United States or in another country, but my answer will assume you're here in the U.S.

If you are not organized as an LLC or corporation then you ***are*** a sole proprietor by default (and definition).  Whatever you receive for your product will be subject to income tax, since it is payment for something you produced, so it would be reported as part of your income.

Before the sale, why not set up a corporation or LLC, transfer the web service code to the new entity as part of your capital contribution, and then when you sell your product, it can be through the corporate entity?  IF you set up as an S corporation then you would only be taxed on whatever you pay yourself as salary (or take as a distribution) instead of the entire amount all at once.  That way you could spread the money out over time (say 3 or 4 years) and not take such a big tax hit for it.  Further, if you do it right, it could be done as some form of dividend rather than salary, so you'd only pay capital gains tax rather than income tax.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I am in the US, however my current job prohibits me from forming an LLC. I know I can do it by ignoring the agreements I have signed, but say I do not want to form an LLC or an S - corp, but rather I would go as a sole proprietor having declaring to the IRS the cost of the transaction as a part of my income. How will I proceed with the deal? Set up a date, transfer the code, receive the money and issue a simple receipt on a sheet of paper declaring that I received this amount for this purpose?

Comment: That's good enough, although there's a bit of a legal thought here too -- you might want to include the understanding that the buyer assumes all legal liability arising from the use of your product and they indemnify you against any and all claims.  This way, if your code is used for bad purposes or ends up creating some potential issues, it gives you a legally defensible position.  You don't want to assume how your buyer will use the code or if they'll sell it to others, so having them agree to assume liability can help shield you from claims brought against them.